# How to change useState variable in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this variable:

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState<string>("initialValue");
```

With a button click I execute this function:

```
const FacebookSign = () => {
    console.log(userName);
    setUserName("value2");
    console.log(userName);
}
```

The `userName` variable doesn't change and my output is:

```
initialValue
initialValue
```

But if I hit the button the second time, I got the output:

```
value2
value2
```

Why doesn't the value change the first time?

Comment: Include your button and onClick code and the code where your FacebookSign function is defined.

Comment: this may be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: My bad sorry thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read about how the state change mechanism works. The process is asynchronous in nature. So may or may not change immediately. Read more about it here [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)

Also you can use useEffect() hook to see the state change immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When you call setSate, [the state is not updated immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately). The state will be updated after a re-render.
You can use useEffect to check the most updated state.

```js
useEffect(() =>{
  console.log(userName)
},[userName])
```