# wait for useState to set values ​and then call function

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native without expo, when trying to set a value with UseState it doesn't set immediately, and I can't get the values ​​in another function.

```
const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        getGridApi().then((response)=>{
            setGridData(response);
            pressed('Mon', 0);
        })
    
}, []);

const pressed = async (category, index) => {
    console.log(gridData); // empty
}
```

How can I make it wait to set and then call the function pressed()

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous , you can use another useEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-state-with-callback) or you can your own custom hook for this. unfortunately react don't provide useState With Callback functionality

Example:

import useStateWithCallback from 'use-state-with-callback';

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallback(0, count => {
    if (count > 1) {
      console.log('Threshold of over 1 reached.');
    } else {
      console.log('No threshold reached.');
    }
  });
 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
 
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Uh, I didn't know this package. Intersting solution. You use it in your code?

Comment: Well well well, tomorrow at work I have to make some modification to a couple of projects... :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, I agree :) What do you think @Leo?

Answer (score 1):

Cioa, unfortunately with hooks, setting state is async and you cannot get the last value in this way. But you can use another `useEffect` hook to retrieve any changes of state variable.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(gridData);  // this shows the last value of gridData setted by the other useEffect
}, [gridData]);
```

But pay attention: this `useEffect` I worte will be triggered every time `gridData` changes his value!