# React Hooks - Which of them are async by default?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been studying and using react hooks for a little bit, I cant seem to find any documentation regarding their state if they are asynchronous  synchronous by default. Is useEffect asynchronous by default?

Comment: all hooks are asynchronous

Comment: @Pavindu source? sorry I cant find any..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)