# useState returns initial value and not updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am forcing below code to run through the `catch` block where it sets `getFoodCategoriesFailed` to `true` and after that when it goes to `finally` block it still shows `getFoodCategoriesFailed` as `false` which is its initial value. Can someone point it out what I am doing wrong and help me fix it.

```
const [getFoodCategoriesFailed, setGetFoodCategoriesFailed] = useState(false);

const getCategories = async (url) => {
  const { request } = await requestor.get({ url });

  request.then((response) => {
    setFoodCategories(response);
    setGetFoodCategoriesFailed(false);
  }).catch(() => {
    setFoodCategories(undefined);
    setGetFoodCategoriesFailed(true);
  }).finally(() => {
    onFoodCategoriesRetrieved(getFoodCategoriesFailed, foodCategories?.food_categories);
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  const url = "xyz";
  getCategories(url);
}, [foodCategories]);
```

Answer (score 0):

useState does not change synchronously

[Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)

If you want to use useState synchronously, use the code below

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useStateCallback(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const cbRef = useRef(null); // mutable ref to store current callback

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
  const setStateCallback = (state, cb) => {
    cbRef.current = cb; // store passed callback to ref
    setState(state);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // cb.current is `null` on initial render, so we only execute cb on state *updates*
    if (cbRef.current) {
      cbRef.current(state);
      cbRef.current = null; // reset callback after execution
    }
  }, [state]);

  return [state, setStateCallback];
}
```

Comment: So after adding above code, do I just need to update below line of code?  
```
const [getFoodCategoriesFailed, setGetFoodCategoriesFailed] = useStateCallback(false);
```

Comment: `const [state, setState] = useStateCallback(0);`


`const onClick= () => setState(prev => prev + 1, data => console.log(data))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert so apologies if this doesn't help, but ... there's a couple of things I might try:

1. Think about whether it might make sense to move onFoodCategoriesRetrieved into the (or as a new) useEffect call (and add getFoodCategoriesFailed to the dependency list).
2. Something like:

```
const getCategories = async (url) => {
  const { request } = await requestor.get({ url });
  let localFoodCategories = undefined;
  let localGetFoodCategoriesFailed = true;
  
  request.then((response) => {
    localFoodCategories = response;
    localGetFoodCategoriesFailed = false;
  }).catch(() => {
  }).finally(() => {
    setFoodCategories(localFoodCategories);
    setGetFoodCategoriesFailed(localGetFoodCategoriesFailed);
    onFoodCategoriesRetrieved(localGetFoodCategoriesFailed, localFoodCategories?.food_categories);
  });
};
```