# after doing authentication from firebase, the data cannot be displayed in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am building a react app in which i am using firebase for authentication. the code is as follows:

```
function signIn(){
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result)=>{
    console.log(result.user);
    setUserInfo(result.user);
    console.log(userInfo);
  }).catch(function(error)=>{
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
```

now when console logging result.user, the data is perfect. but when i assign it to userInfo and console log it, it returns an empty object with something like this-

```
{proto}
```

Comment: Hey Tam2006. Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the setter of a `useState` hook are asynchronous, so you can't log the state variable straight after calling `setUserInfo`.

If you want to get the updates state, you can use a `useEffect` hook. But within your  current `then()` listener I'd recommend simply sticking to `result.user`.

Also see:

- [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)
- [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)