# React useEffect with several HTTP calls

Tags: reactjs, http, use-effect

I am attempting to make many HTTP calls in a component using useEffect and useState to store the results of this http call. I thought I had a basic understanding of how useEffect works but I am confused as to why my code isn't working and therefore must be implementing it wrong.

Here is my useEffect hook code in my dashboard component:

```
useEffect(() => {       
    isMounted.current = true;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (survey === null) {
        const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');
        setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);
      }

      if (teamInfo === null) {
        const teamInfoResponse = await getTeamInfo(user.teamId);
        setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse.data);
      }

      if (week === null || year === null) {
        const weekAndYearResponse = await getWeekAndYear();
        setWeek(weekAndYearResponse.data.weekNumber);
        setYear(weekAndYearResponse.data.year);
      }

      if (week && year && !stats) {
        const statsResponse = await getTeamSurveyStats(week, year, user.teamId);
        setStats(statsResponse.data);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      // executed when unmount
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [survey, teamInfo, week, year, stats, user.teamId]);
```

I thought that checking to see if the state value I was setting for the return of each call, I could chuck this http call inside a conditional and it would only make the http request on re-render if that variable was null, as I define this using useState(null).

When I check my network tab I see the following:

[image]

The first call only runs once which is correct - this is getSurveys
the second call runs twice which is incorrect as only needs to run once - this is getTeamInfo
the third call runs 5 times which is strange as only needs to run once - this is getWeekAndYear
the fourth call runs only once which is correct.

Can anyone see why 2 of these calls are running several times?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to walk you through what happens on the first 2 calls so that you're able to extrapolate what happens for the rest.

When your Dashboard element loads for the first time, `useEffect` runs your code. Specifically, it runs this function `fetchData`.

`fetchData` sees that `survey` is null and runs this code:

```
const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');
setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);
```

When that code calls `setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);` and updates your state variable, which I assume is `survey`, `useEffect` runs again. And it does so before finishing the original on-mount run. So now you have 2 `fetchData` calls in the pipe, one of which is partially finished. We will call them 1st and 2nd.

The 1st is now at this block and is likely awaiting the `getTeamInfo` call:

```
const teamInfoResponse = await getTeamInfo(user.teamId);
setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse.data);
```

Meanwhile, the 2nd swoops in and goes straing into the same block of code (because `survey` is no longer null, but `teamInfo` still is). So now both 1st and 2nd are running `const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');`

Hence the 2 calls for `getTeamInfo`.

Then this:

```
setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse.data);
```

triggers another useEffect run, this time because `teamInfo` got updated. I think you get the picture...

Comment: Hi, Yes that makes complete sense. I have only been using React for 9 months after using Angular for 7+ years so hooks are relatively new to me. I thought once a rerender was called after setting the first state variable the original useEffect call was cancelled!

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook is called each time when some of the values passed in the array are changed.
It will be called the second time after the `survey` is changed, but `timeInfo` isn't loaded at that time, so the request will be duplicated, and this will happen for each other variables. Also, this is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54120692/14349629.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect is called each time any variable of the array(which is passed as a second parameter).

Try following code

```
useEffect(() => {       
    isMounted.current = true;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (survey === null) {
        const surveyResponse = await getSurveys('standard');
        setSurvey(surveyResponse.data);
        return;
      }

      if (teamInfo === null) {
        const teamInfoResponse = await getTeamInfo(user.teamId);
        setTeamInfo(teamInfoResponse.data);
        return;
      }

      let weekAndYearResponse = {};
      if (week === null || year === null) {
        weekAndYearResponse = await getWeekAndYear();
        setWeek(weekAndYearResponse.data.weekNumber);
        setYear(weekAndYearResponse.data.year);
      }

      if (weekAndYearResponse.data.weekNumber && weekAndYearResponse.year && !stats) {
        const statsResponse = await getTeamSurveyStats(weekAndYearResponse.data.weekNumber, weekAndYearResponse.year, user.teamId);
        setStats(statsResponse.data);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      // executed when unmount
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [user.teamId]);
```