# React setState doesn't update boolean variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a state variable using

```
const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false)
```

Then I've this button which should update the value of `drawing`

```
 <button onClick={() => toggleDrawing}>Toggle Drawing</button>
```

The toggleDrawing function is:

```
const toggleDrawing = () => {
    setDrawing(true)
  }
```

but when I press the button and console.log the value of `drawing` id doesn't update, it's always a step behind. it start with a value of `false`, after one click it remains `false` and after the second click it switches to `true`.

Comment: You're not calling the function

Comment: Where is `console.log` in your code? `setDrawing` runs asynchronously maybe that is why the state doesn't update

Comment: Your onClick returns the function instead of calling it. Either pass the function itself instead of the anonymous arrow function, or call the function instead of/when returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false)
```

#### Case:1 If you want a toggle true=>false and false=>true

```js
const toggleDrawing = () => {
    setDrawing(!drawing);
  }

<button onClick={toggleDrawing}>Toggle Drawing</button>
```

#### Case:2 If you just want to set it to true

```js
 const toggleDrawing = () => {
    setDrawing(true);
  }

<button onClick={toggleDrawing}>Toggle Drawing</button>
```

Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-meadow-thdni?file=/src/App.js

**Note =>** console.log(drawing) in toggleDrawing function will return false at first then true reason is state is not updated

Comment: I did the same thing you explained, but it is not solved. here is my full code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/misty-night-dm66l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You cannot console.log in the toggleDrawing function react state is not updated if you call console.log outside of it will show true

Comment: I need to access the drawing variable and do something with it inside the function with the new updated value.

Comment: you can use useEffect for it

Comment: i will attach it in sanbox wait a minute

Comment: @AymanTarig https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-meadow-thdni?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

```
const toggleDrawing = () => {
    setDrawing((oldValue) => !oldValue)
  }
```

if you want to toggle state in React you always want to refer to the previous state

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

You're just returning the `toggleDrawing` function without executing it

#### Solution

Execute the function when the click event occurs like this

```html
<button onClick={() => toggleDrawing()}>Toggle Drawing</button>
```

Or pass the `toggleDrawing` to onClick as the actual function like

```html
<button onClick={toggleDrawing}>Toggle Drawing</button>
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/misty-night-dm66l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It's actually working.  The thing is, you're trying to access `drawing` immediately after you set it but you can't because [React setter hooks method is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous). @AymanTarig