# problem call `useContext` then my other `state` set to default value

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state, use-context, createcontext

in my code i used one `context` for saving data and one `state` for get active id . my problem is when i `setState` and then  `setContext` , when i get `state` value i see `state` set default value !

```
export default function AddKnowledgeScreen({ route, navigation }) {

  const { TmpKnowledge, SetTmpKnowledge } = useContext(addKnowledgeContext);

   const [activeKnowlegeId, SetactiveKnowlegeId] = useState(-1);

  const myref = useRef(null);

return(
     <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: Color.Background, }}>
          <Button
                onPress={() => {
                         SetactiveKnowlegeId(5);
                         var knowledgeData = { Id: 5, Name: "jack" };
                         SetTmpKnowledge(knowledgeData);
                        }>
          </Button>
     </View>
);
}
```

i found that when i set my `context` Screen reRendered and all `state` set with default values !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question correctly,but I understand that you are trying to set your local state and right away use this new value to set your value in your context

If so, this would be because useState hook is asynchronous hence you still get the default value when setting your context value

Here are some links with more explanation in detail:

[Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

[Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)

Comment: i found when i set my context , page rerender and all state go to default value . i don't wanna that !!