# increase const onClick but dont work first calling

Tags: logging, count, console, hook, counter

**I want to increase a counter, it's working but not in first calling...**

```
        const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
          function handleClick(){
            setCount(count+5)
            console.log(count)
          }
```

**when I call for first time the function, it should shows "5" directly because I wrote console.log after the increase but in first calling, it shows 0... after (second click) it shows 5... I dont understand**

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it's because the update isn't applied yet in this render. You are updating the state value and trying to access the same value in one render, that won't work. [See this answer also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)

If you are looking to do something based on the state's new value, you can use the useEffect hook.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
function handleClick(){
   setCount(count+5)
}
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(count)
}, [count])
```