# React- is useState synchronous (not the setter returned by useState but useState itself)?

Tags: reactjs

```
const Child = (props) =>
{
    const {data1, data2} = props;
    let defaultData = [];
    //do some logic based on data1 and data2 e.g.
    defaultData.push(data1 + data2); 
    const [myStateData, myStateDataSetter] = useState(defaultData);
    console.log(myStateData);
}
```

Will myStateData always be defined? (I understand that myStateDataSetter(newData) is async - that is not my question; I am asking if the first assignment using the default param to useState is synchronous).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous
You can check that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Given

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(initialValue);
```

When the component mounts, `someState` will always be `initialValue` - it won't be `undefined` or anything else that requires a re-render before the state gets initially populated.