# Firestore Async function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, react-query

So I'm trying to use React Query with Firestore and usually this works pretty fine but recently I have been unable to make a function that returns a value.

```
const fetchProduct = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "notes"));
  const arr = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setNotes(doc.data())


  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
  });

  return notes
}
```

I'm later trying to use this function with React Query like this -

```
const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery(['todos'], fetchProduct)
```

However the value of the {data} always return to undefined but however once the `fetchProduct()` function is called manually it all works.

Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state is an asynchronous operation in React (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)), so the value of `notes` isn't set yet by the time your `return notes` runs.

If you want to return the value synchronously:

```
return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

More typically though, you'll want to put the code that depends on that return value into its own `useEffect` hook that depends on the `notes` state.

Also see:

- [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/209103)
- [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)
- [Is useState synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119678/is-usestate-synchronous)

Comment: Honestly, I dont have to set state, I tried it cause nothing else was working. I just want the async function to return a value which will be then handled by React Query. However I'm unable to make an async function that just returns the `doc.data()` so far.

Comment: I tried `return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());` however it doesn't work either.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is incredibly hard to help with.  I don't know anything about `useQuery`, but does it know how to deal with asynchronous data?

Comment: Yes it only accepts an async function that returns a value,

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, you should not set inside the foreach function

```
const fetchProduct = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "notes"));
  const notes = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((note) => {
    notes.push({ ...note.data(), id: note.id })
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
  });
  return notes;
}

// in the place of the calling the function
const notes = await fetchProduct();
setNotes(notes);
```

Note: don't use variable name as doc in foreach, instead use some other variable name like since doc is built in function of firebase you might have imported it