# React doesn't render latest state

Tags: reactjs

I have the following problem.

```
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ a: 0 });

    const handleClick = () => {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            const _state = { a: 1 };

            console.log("1");
            setState(_state);

            console.log("2");
            _state.a = 2;
            setState(_state);

            console.log("3");
            _state.a = 3;
            setState(_state);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
            <br />
            {console.log("render", state)}
            {state.a}
        </div>
    );
}
```

After I click the button, following output is shown in the console:

```
1
render {a: 1}
2
render {a: 2}
3
```

But it renders `{a: 1}` instead of `{a: 2}`

So at the end state is changed and its value is `{a: 3}`, but react doesn't render new value.In react devtools I can clearly see `state: {a: 3}`.
If I remove `Promise.resolve` the code will work as expected.

Additional question is, why does it invoke render in the middle of the code (after `console.log(1)`?

Here is the full example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-platform-0j45u

Comment: I updated my answer so hopefully it makes it clear why `render` doesn't show the latest value and why `renders` are triggered on every `setState` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In promise callback, you set the state **only once** on the first `setState(_state);`, on every other try, the component doesn't render because as React rendering works, it makes **shallow comparison** with the previous state, which is always true because it holds the same object reference (it's javascript):

```
const state = { a: 1};
setState(state); // prevState = state;

state.a = 2;
prevState === state // always true so not render is triggered
```

Its a common beginner mistake, React states to [treat state as immutable.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state).

- [`setState API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Yes I did know that. But the problem is that state is changed, its value is now `{a: 3}` but it renders old value?

Comment: Changing the value doesn't trigger render, diff state is one reason to trigger render.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. And regarding the second part of my question, why does it invoke render in the middle of the code?

Comment: Because `setState` is async (check the docs), so after a few seconds of calling the first `setState`, when the conditions are met, the component will render.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `React` is not rendering the latest state is because you're directly manipulating `state` by doing the following:

```js
const _state = { a: 1 };

setState(_state);

// you're using the same object
_state.a = 2;
setState(_state);

// you're using the same object here too
_state.a = 3;
setState(_state);
```

**You should not be mutating `state` directly and you should treat `state` as it were immutable.**

To fix this, you need to make a copy of your `state`, update whatever properties you want, and then use that new object to update your `state`.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    const _state = { a: 1 };

    console.log("1");
    setState(_state);

    console.log("2");
    const _state2 = { ..._state, a: 2 };
    setState(_state2);

    console.log("3");
    const _state3 = { ..._state, a: 3 };
    setState(_state3);
    console.log("3");
  });
};
```

Here's a working example:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-driscoll-gkhgp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

Also, `React` will batch `state` updates so sometimes if you're not seeing "correct behavior" when you call `setState` multiple times in a row for the same piece of state it's because `React` is trying to prevent unnecessary re-renders by batching those updates. In your case, however, they will not be batched since they are triggered in a `Promise`.

See here for more information on how batching works in regards to state updates:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048903/5862900)