# How to set 2 states asynchronously in React using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have this function:

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([]);
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

const addRow = () => {
    setNumbers([...numbers, numbers.length+1]);
    setRows([...rows,
        <NewGradeRow key={numbers[numbers.length-1]} number={numbers[numbers.length-1]}/>]);
}
```

that is supposed to add new rows. It should be adding a new value to the numbers hook, then using the new value in the numbers hook to add a new row in the rows hook. It runs synchronously though and the new row doesn't use the new value given to the numbers hook. How would I fix this?

Comment: Consider only storing your data in state and using that to return React elements (JSX) from your components, [not storing React elements in state itself](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state).

Answer (score 1):

Take the new values from the *calculation performed* (one plus the length of the original `numbers`), rather from the `numbers` variable (which hasn't updated yet):

```
const addRow = () => {
    const newNum = numbers.length + 1;
    setNumbers([...numbers, newNum]);
    setRows([...rows,
        <NewGradeRow
          key={newNum}
          number={newNum}
        />
    ]);
};
```

You could also use `useEffect` to watch for changes to `numbers`. Remove the `setRows` from `addRow`, and do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newNum = numbers[numbers.length - 1];
    setRows([...rows,
        <NewGradeRow
          key={newNum}
          number={newNum}
        />
    ]);
}, numbers.length);
```

(if the length of `numbers` can change from other sources as well, you'll have to factor that into the logic)

Answer (score 1):

You have some misunderstanding here. First, `setNumbers` and `setRows` actually run **asynchronous**, in a sense that they are batched together to change state only once and not individually run and change app state twice. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks) to understand this issue.

Second, you cannot get the "updated" value of the state immediately. This has somethings to do with closure. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) or [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to understand more about this problem. This issue apply for both callback and hooks

Answer (score 0):

is " NewGradeRow " a jsx component ??
if so i doubt it could be called or stated in setRows state instaed it should be seperated from the setRows state and put in the return statement.

Comment: Is there a way to force a render then force a 2nd render?