# Are React useEffect hooks guaranteed to execute in order?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Let's say I have this:

```js
function Example(props) {
  const { prop1, prop2 } = props;
  const latestProp1 = useRef(prop1);

  useEffect(() => {
    latestProp1.current = prop1;
  }, [prop1]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(latestProp1.current);
  }, [prop2]);

  return null;
}
```

If both `prop1` and `prop2` change in the same re-render, is it guaranteed that the console would log the *new* `prop1` value?

And if I swap the useEffect hooks' position -

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(latestProp1.current);
  }, [prop2]);

  useEffect(() => {
    latestProp1.current = prop1;
  }, [prop1]);
```

would it be guaranteed that the console would log the *old* `prop1` value (from before the render)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if you follow the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), the call order ensured (hooks are called via array index, check how hooks implemented).

> By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

Therefore, by simulating a [batched set state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks) (both `prop1` and `prop2` change in the same re-render) you can notice that `first` will always be logged before `second`:

```
function Example(props) {
  const { prop1, prop2 } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("first");
  }, [prop1]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("second");
  }, [prop2]);

  return <>Example</>;
}

function Component() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = React.useState(0);

  const together = () => {
    setCounter2((p) => p + 1);
    setCounter((p) => p + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Example prop1={counter} prop2={counter2} />
      <button onClick={together}>together</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Example Batching Call Order]

Comment: Thank you! It is apparently true that React effects are ordered. But about the Rule of Hooks - isn't the order of hooks for React to tell one hook from another (e.g. to identify which state value corresponds to which `useState()`)?

Comment: Yes, it differents each hook from another by its defined order, and also called in this order (depends on which hook should be called)