# How React manage state updates wrapped in async block

Tags: reactjs

In this code i expect when i clicked asycn change button to have output:
num1: 6
num1: 7

as each state update in then() block so React does not batch the updates

but i got 2 lines:
num1: 6

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
const Test = (props) => {
const [num1, setNum1] = useState(5);
const [num2, setNum2] = useState(6);

const syncClickHandler = () => {
 setNum1(num1 + 1);
 setNum1(num1 + 1);
};

console.log("num1 " + num1);

const asyncClickHandler = () => {
 Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    setNum1(num1 + 1);
  })
  .then(() => {
    setNum1(num1 + 1);
  });
};
return (
 <div>
  num1: {num1} , num2: {num2} <br />
  <Button onClick={syncClickHandler}>sync change</Button>
  <Button onClick={asyncClickHandler}>async change</Button>
 </div>
 );
};
export default Test;
```

why i got this output

Comment: Why don't you do only one `setNum1` ? What is your use case?

Comment: i am just trying to understand React state update in async function and in direct event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React [does not batch state updates in async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks) (yet v17, may change in future).

Moreover, you have [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `num1` value (`num1 === 6`), so the second `setNum` call won't trigger additional render (`prev value 7 === curr value 7`).

Try using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) and discard the closure:

```
const asyncClickHandler = () => {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
    })
    .then(() => {
      setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
    });
};
```

A full example, notice the number of logs, sync set state are batched and async aren't.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const syncClickHandler = () => {
    setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
    setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const asyncClickHandler = () => {
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setNum((prev) => prev + 1);
      });
  };

  console.log("num " + num);

  return (
    <div>
      num1: {num} <br />
      <button onClick={syncClickHandler}>sync change</button>
      <button onClick={asyncClickHandler}>async change</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]

Comment: ok i know that will be fine , but i am wondering why this is not working as i used async wrapper for each state update and react will not batch these 2 updates

Comment: React does not batch promises. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks

Comment: i know that react does not batch promises, so why i did not get the expected result, as i think after resolving promise react will do the first then block that update state and after that update the state in the second then block

Comment: Ok and what is the problem then?

Comment: yes i ask why i did not get the expected result as i thought

Comment: But you do get the expected results, log of 6, then button press 7 and 8, you have two setState

Comment: did you mean that closure is the reason not react state update, ok fine could you explain more about the closure

Comment: All relevant links are in the answer. You can read on closures from it.