# Why must I pass a function to the setter function of 'useState' in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm handling file uploads using `react-dropzone`, which calls the following function with a list of files:

```js
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

    const onDrop = useCallback(async acceptedFiles => {
        uploadFiles(acceptedFiles)
    }, [])
```

I then upload the files using fetch:

```js
    const uploadFiles = async acceptedFiles => {
        acceptedFiles.forEach(async (file) => {
            setFiles(array => [...array, fileState])

            await fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            }).then(res => {
                // etc
            })
        })
    }
```

If I replace the `setFiles` call with just `setFiles([...files, fileState])` (not in a function) it breaks, but why is this?

Comment: `setFiles(array => [...array, fileState])` apparently takes a function reference. So if you pass an array it won't make any sense.

Comment: `useState` also returns a function that should take a value in.  The first documentation example (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) suggests that you can call `setCount(count + 1)`.

Comment: Oh I see, `setFiles` is actually a useState function. My bad, I thought it was some random function related to react-dropzone. When you say "it breaks", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: `files` seems to render as if it contains only the latest item added to the array.  When logging `console.log(files)` within the uploadFiles function it's always empty.  This happens even if I've called `setState([...files, fileState])` multiple times.  When I change the code ot `setState(array => [...array, fileState])` it works as anticipated.

Comment: Both of those calls should in theory work, I will give you that. Any way to reproduce this in a sandbox?

Comment: When you say 'it breaks', do you mean it errors or it just doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: I'll see if I can get a reproducible example.  By 'it breaks' I mean the array is always empty and it _appears_ as if `setState()` isn't actually changing the variable (although weirdly it does do a re-render and update the UI?!).  This results in multiple calls to setState meaning only the most recent file uploaded is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I was able to reproduce the issue you're having. https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bouman-9lb5k?file=/src/App.js

Here is the relevant code:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(["file1", "file2"]);

  const uploadFiles = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach(async (file) => {
      //setFiles([...files, file]);
      setFiles(array => [...array, file])

      await fetch("https://httpstat.us/200");
    });
  };

  const testFunc = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    uploadFiles(["file3", "file4"]);
  };
```

If behaves as expected when called like the above, but if you swap the `setFiles` calls, only `file4` will be appended.

The issue appears to be related to React batching setState calls as they are made in close succession. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks) provides the best answer I could find.

So it appears that when you call your setFiles with the callback, React does not batch those requests and thus executes them one after the other.