# What's the best way to batch state updates from async calls in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks) that React doesn't automatically batch state updates, in the case that an event is `non-react` based i.e. setTimeout, Promise calls. (In short any event from Web APIs.)

This differs from `react-based` events, such as those from onClick events (etc), which are batched by react to limit renders. This is well illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048903/11664580), which essentially demonstrates that while this only triggers one render:

```js
  function handleClickWithoutPromise() {
    setA('aa');
    setB('bb');
  }
```

This will trigger two:

```js
  function handleClickWithPromise() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      setA('aa');
      setB('bb');
    });
  }
```

For me this is problematic, since on my first page load I sent a request to my back-end and receive various data that is used to update numerous discrete state objects. This triggers a dozen re-renders, which is obviously not optimal.

There are some options offered on different posts, but would appreciate some expert guidance as to which is best practice:

- Redux (I haven't used this library yet and am apprehensive about overhauling my state handling). This also seems like such a common issue that I would have thought React had it's own native way of batching async state updates.
- userReducer and bundle all of my state into one. I can then update everything with one update of state. This doesn't make sense given how my different state would intuitively make more sense being kept discrete.
- Use `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => { ... })`, as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523100/11664580)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, just in case no better answers are forthcoming, I found this [article on Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2) that shows a really good, simple example of the `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => { ... })` working. (You have to scroll a way down to the section: **"How to force batching?"**).

The author also adds that:

> Although this function is supposedly “unstable”, React apparently
> intends to address this in the following versions.

> **“In future versions
> (probably React 17 and later), React will batch all updates by default
> so you won’t have to think about this”**, according to Dan Abramov.

Comment: React v17 is here, should be trivial to test, right? A quick scan, I didn't see anything mentioned other than a revamping in (experimental) concurrent mode: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html