# if user type existing email in the text field, button should be disabled in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
  const [mail, useEmail] = useState("");
  const [disabled, useDisabled] = useState(false)
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    useEmail(e.target.value)
  }
  if (mail.includes('s@gmail.com')) {

    React.useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        useDisabled(true);
      }, 2000);
    })
  } else {
    useDisabled(false)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        value={ mail }
        onChange={ handleChange }
        maxLength="20" 
      />
      <button 
        disabled={ mail.length < 1 }
      > Submit </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

but at the time it throws error like "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." how to resolve that error?

Comment: It is tradition to name the set function returned by `useState` as `setSomething` not `useSomething`. React names hooks `useSomething` so you violating that convention makes your code really hard to follow.

Comment: Why are you setting `disabled` to `true` with `useInterval`?

Comment: You are also calling your `useEffect` inside the if function. Never call Hooks inside loops, conditions or nested functions.

Comment: when existing email user type that time button should be disabled or else useDisabled button false value return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL.DR:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function DropDown() {
    const [mail, setEmail] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <input value={mail} onChange={handleChange} maxLength={20} />
            <button disabled={mail.includes("s@gmail.com") || mail.length < 1}> Submit </button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Let's break it down:

1. Hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`, etc) cannot be conditionally rendered, so you cannot write them inside `if else` statements.
2. `const [mail, setMail] = useState("")`. The second attribute should be `setSomething`, not `useSomething`. The `useSomething` should be reserved to the declarations of new hooks. The `setMail` returned by the `useState` is not a hook, but a normal function (the `useState` itself is the hook).
3. `setState` (or `setDisabled`, in your example) should never be used directly inside the render of a component. A `setState` causes the component to re-render so, if when re-rendering a `setState` is encountered, it will trigger another re-render, that will trigger another `setState`, and so on (leading to the ""Too many re-renders." you had). Generally speaking, `setState` should only be used on event handlers (such as `onClick`, `onKeyDown`, `onSomethingElseHapped`, etc)

There are a few more minor issues with your code. I encourage you to go through the [basics of react](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) one more time.

Comment: Why not call setDisabled inside handleChange instead of useEffect?

Comment: thanks a lot. it's now working fine

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo you are absolutely right. Edited.

Comment: Yes perfect @juliomrc, Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React functional component. We can check more depth details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: @juliomrc I think that states changes are asynchronous, so is possible that `mail` is not up to date when `mail.includes("s@gmail.com") || mail.length < 1` gets evaluated. Try assign `const mail = e.target.value` first

Comment: As of today, unless inside a `async function`, react batches the `setStates`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks

There is no need to keep the `disabled` in state though, so on that part you are correct.

Comment: No need to use a state for disabled. You can simply add a constant on each render. unnecessary create a state. will retrigger render.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need to create a state for the disabled. You can simply validate using it on every render. The sample is given below. Whenever you update input, the component will retrigger and validation will be performed.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const blackListed = /^s@gmail\.com$/;
const emailReg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;

const isEmailValid = (email = "") => {
  if (!email.length) return false;
  if (!emailReg.test(email)){
    return false
  }
  return !blackListed.test(email);
};
export default function App() {
  const [mail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setEmail(value);
  };
  const isValidEmail = isEmailValid(mail);
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={mail} onChange={handleChange} maxLength="20" />
      <button disabled={!isValidEmail}> Submit </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to clear email after a certain time. You can use useEffect with setTimeout and watch for change.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isValidEmail && mail.length) {
        alert("Your email is invalid");
        setEmail("")
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [isValidEmail])
```

**Complete code:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const blackListed = /^s@gmail\.com$/;
const emailReg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;

const isEmailValid = (email = "") => {
  if (!email.length) return false;
  if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
    return false
  }
  return !blackListed.test(email);
};


export default function App() {
  const [mail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setEmail(value);
  };
  const isValidEmail = isEmailValid(mail);

  // Clear after some toat and message.
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!isValidEmail && mail.length) {
        alert("Your email is invalid");
        setEmail("")
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [isValidEmail])

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={mail} onChange={handleChange} maxLength="20" />
      <button disabled={!isValidEmail}> Submit </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Working code:**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/nervous-cache-tm5yt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark