# Why is useEffect(()={...},[]) not being called on component load?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

There are numerous questions relating to useEffect() and running on initial page render.  I am experiencing the same problem even after making sure my code is correct regarding parameters passed to useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        setRole(Cookies.get('role'));
        fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/user-details`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "user_id": role,
                "language": "en",
                "api_token": token
            })
        })
            .then((user) => user.json())
            .then((thisUserData) => {
                if (thisUserData.status_code == 200) {
                    setThisUser(thisUserData)
                }
            })
    }, [])
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to be called after the component mounts.

Here is the full page code:

```
import Header from "../../../components/header"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import Link from 'next/link'
import Pagination from "../../../components/datatable/pagination"
import Cookies from "js-cookie"
import { parseCookies } from "nookies"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import UserSidebar from "../../../components/user_sidebar"
import TabButtonUser from "../../../components/tabbuttonuser"
import Address from "../../../components/address"


const AdminUsers = ({ data }) => {

    const router = useRouter()
    // const limit = 3
    // const lastPage = Math.ceil(totalPage / limit)
    // console.log(data)
    // console.log(listUsers)

    /**
     * Manage states
     */

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);

    const [fullNname, setFullName] = useState("");
    const [emailID, setEmailID] = useState("");
    const [country_code, setCountry_code] = useState("");
    const [phone_number, setPhone_number] = useState("");
    const [company_access, setCompany_access] = useState("");
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState("");
    const [userID, setUserId] = useState("");
    const [role, setRole] = useState("");
    const [thisUserData, setThisUser] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        setRole(Cookies.get('role'));
        fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/user-details`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "user_id": role,
                "language": "en",
                "api_token": token
            })
        })
            .then((user) => user.json())
            .then((thisUserData) => {
                if (thisUserData.status_code == 200) {
                    setThisUser(thisUserData)
                }
            })
    }, [])
    
    /**
     * Clear values
     */
    const handleClose = () => {
        setShow(false)
        setIsEdit(false);
        setUserId("")
        setFullName("");
        setEmailID("");
        setCountry_code("");
        setPhone_number("");
    };
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);





    /**
     * Add User
     * @param {*} e 
     * @returns 
     */
    const addUser = async (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        if (!token) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    permanent: false,
                },
            }
        }
        const resUser = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/create-sub-admin`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "full_name": fullNname,
                "email_id": emailID,
                "country_code": "+1",
                "phone_number": phone_number,
                "api_token": token
            })
        })

        const res2User = await resUser.json();
        console.log(res2User);
        if (res2User.status_code == 200) {
            handleClose();
            setFullName("");
            setEmailID("");
            setCountry_code("");
            setPhone_number("");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user details basis of user id for edit purpose
     * @param {*} id 
     * @returns 
     */
    const getUser = async (id) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        setIsEdit(true);
        setShow(true);
        setUserId(id)
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        if (!token) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    permanent: false,
                },
            }
        }
        const userData = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/user-details`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "user_id": id,
                "language": "en",
                "api_token": token
            })

        })
        const userData2 = await userData.json();
        console.log(userData2);
        if (userData2.status_code == 200) {
            // handleClose();
            setFullName(userData2?.data?.full_name);
            setEmailID(userData2?.data?.email_id);
            setCountry_code(userData2?.data?.phone_number?.country_code);
            setPhone_number(userData2?.data?.phone_number?.phone_number);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove user 
     * Api is pending
     * @param {*} id 
     */
    const removeUser = async (id) => {

    }
    /**
     *Update User
     *
     * @return {*} 
     */
    const updateUser = async () => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const token = Cookies.get('token');
        if (!token) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/',
                    permanent: false,
                },
            }
        }
        const resUser = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/update-user`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "user_id": userID,
                "full_name": fullNname,
                "email_id": emailID,
                "country_code": "+1",
                "phone_number": phone_number,
                "api_token": token,
                "is_active": isActive
            })

        })
        const res2User = await resUser.json();
        console.log(res2User);
        if (res2User.status_code == 200) {

            setFullName("");
            setEmailID("");
            setCountry_code("");
            setPhone_number("");
            setIsEdit(false);
            setShow(false);
            setUserId("")
        }
    }

    const address = {
        "address_line": "",
        "city_name": "",
        "state_name": "",
        "zip_code": ""
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-3">
                        <UserSidebar data={thisUserData} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <div className="sidebarwrap">
                            {/* <TabButtonUser id={data?._id} /> */}
                            <h3 className="acc_title">My Company</h3>
                            <h2 className="login_name">Alliance Credit</h2>
                            <div className="acc_email">
                                <a href="mailto:email@company.com">email@company.com</a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="acc_phone">+1234567890</div>
                            <Address address={address} />


                            <div className="ac_left acc_title">All Team Members</div>
                            <div className="ac_right">
                                {role.indexOf('admin') > -1 ?
                                    <button className="btn btnedit" onClick={handleShow}>Add Sub-Admin</button>
                                    : ''}
                            </div>
                            <div className="clearfix"></div>
                            <div className="listing">
                                <table id="example" className="table table-striped">

                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><div>Sr. Number</div></th>
                                            <th><div>User Name</div></th>
                                            <th><div>Date Added</div></th>
                                            <th><div>Email</div></th>

                                            <th><div>Actions</div></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {data?.map((item, index) => (


                                            <tr key={index}>
                                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                                <td>{item.full_name}</td>
                                                <td>{item.date_added}</td>
                                                <td>{item.email_id}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <>
                                                        <button className="btn viewmore" onClick={() => getUser(item._id)}>Edit User</button>
                                                    </>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        ))}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                {/* <Pagination page={page} totalPage={totalPage} lastPage={lastPage} /> */}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{isEdit == false
                        ? "Add Sub-Admin"
                        : "Edit Sub-Admin"
                    }</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <div className="popupform">
                        <form method="POST">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">


                                    <label htmlFor="fullname" className="form-label">Full Name</label>
                                    <input className="form-control" name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname" value={fullNname} onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <label htmlFor="emailID" className="form-label">Email</label>
                                    <input className="form-control" name="emailID" type="text" id="emailID" value={emailID} onChange={(e) => setEmailID(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    <label htmlFor="phone_number" className="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input className="form-control" name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number" value={phone_number} onChange={(e) => setPhone_number(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col">
                                    {isEdit ? (
                                        <>
                                            <label htmlFor="phone_number" className="form-label">Active status</label>
                                            <select className="form-control form-select" onChange={(e) => setActive(e.target.value)}>
                                                <option value="0">Active</option>
                                                <option value="1">Deactivate</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </>
                                    ) : ''
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input className="form-control" name="userID" type="hidden" id="company_logo_en" value={userID} />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    {isEdit == false
                        ? <>
                            <Button variant="secondary" className="btn btnedit" onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                            <Button variant="primary" onClick={addUser}>Add User</Button>
                        </>
                        :
                        <>
                            <Button variant="primary" className="btn btnremove" onClick={removeUser}>Remove User</Button>
                            <Button variant="primary" className="btn btnedit">Reset User</Button>
                            <Button variant="primary" onClick={updateUser}>Save</Button>
                        </>
                    }
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @export
 * @param {*} { query: { page = 1, data = null, totalPage = 10 } }
 * @return {*} 
 */
// export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { page = 1, data = null, totalPage = 10 } }) {
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
    // const start = +page === 1 ? 0 : (+page + 1)

    // const { locale, locales, defaultLocale, asPath } = useRouter();
    const { token } = parseCookies(ctx)

    if (!token) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/list-sub-admin`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "language": 'en',
            "api_token": token,
        })

    })

    const data = await res.json()


    /** 
     * limit, start, search item
     */
    return {
        props: {
            data: data?.data || [],
        }
    }

}

export default AdminUsers
```

I am sure it is something simple that I've missed (it usually is) but I can't seem to spot it.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Here is the full page code"* This isn't really all that useful. We only see the `AdminUsers` component. That's not enough for use to run your code. It would be much better if you created an online sandbox of your project. Try https://codesandbox.io/, for example.

Comment: Is it really not called, or are you getting a non-200 response from the fetch request due to `role` still having its initial value? Setting state is an asynchronous operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately.

Comment: It appeared to not be called as none of my breakpoints was hitting anywhere in the function.  However the answer given by @Max  solved the problem.  It appears that a call to state was causing the page to re-render before the useEffect() could complete, making it appear as if it were not being called at all.  Remove the useState() call solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear for me this problem, but I try to write what I see: you have defined useEffect with the fetch without deps. In that fetch you use role state which is initialized to empty string in the first time. You set the role using setRole in the same useEffect but this has no effect for the precedent reasons.

My suggestion is to remove role state and redefine useEffect like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get('token');
    const role = Cookies.get('role');
    fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/user/user-details`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_id: role,
        language: 'en',
        api_token: token,
      }),
    })
      .then((user) => user.json())
      .then((thisUserData) => {
        if (thisUserData.status_code == 200) {
          setThisUser(thisUserData);
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

React's state setters are asynchronous([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks)), so when you use 'role' right after 'setRole', role is still an empty string. Thus the fetch returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may not be directly related to the question itself, but it may be useful to an another developer who is searching for an answer.

In my case I had two components and change rendering them when a button was clicked on the interface and I had accidentally put [] in dependencies, I fixed it by removing it.

Before,

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your function
},[]);
```

After

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your function
});
```