# How to respond to rapid/sequential state updates with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I am having trouble getting my head around state management in React.
I'm tempted to say its rubbish but I know in truth I'm just not understanding some fundamental thing. I've set up [a simple example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WHs7FfN7CKPUFnsD) that basically illustrates what I'm trying to do

```
const Hello = ()=>{
  const [myArr, setMyArr] = useState([]);

  const addToArr = ()=>{
    setMyArr(arr => arr.concat(arr.length+1));
  }

  const clearArr = ()=>{
    setMyArr(arr => [])
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(myArr);
  }, [myArr]);

  return <div>
    <button onClick={addToArr}>Add</button>
    <button onClick={clearArr}>Clear</button>
    <button onClick={()=>{
      clearArr();
      addToArr();
    }}>Clear Then Add</button>
  </div>
}
export default Hello;
```

Run the preview and you'll see three buttons. With the dev tools console open click the buttons.
**Add** and **Clear** work as expected and result in an array with 1 additional item or an empty array.
**Clear Then Add** is where I am confused. The final outcome is correct, an array with 1 item, but I would expect to see an empty array logged first.

I've read a bunch of stuff about how state updates are async and React is trying to minimise rerenders and what-have-you but in my instance I need to respond to that empty array.
I have a few components that watch the list and some of then need to know if updates are taking the form of items being added to an existing list or items being added after the list was cleared.
I've also read that you should not call methods of child components in React.

So is there a way to respond to that first clearing of the list?

Also, what might that fundamental concept be that I'm not getting because to my thinking, having async state updates just seems like a massive headache if you have no way knowing when they are complete or listening for when they happen.
Again, I'm sure its my structure that is the issue but its really annoying me and I need to rant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React 16 it should be the case that multiple enqueued state updates will be batch processed *unless* they are triggered asynchronously. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048903/8690857) for explanation.

Example:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      clearArr();
      addToArr();
    });
  }}
>
  Clear Then Add
</button>
```

React updates are processed asynchronously, but they ***are not*** `async`, meaning the state updater function isn't `async` and can't be awaited. This means you can't enqueue a state update, wait for it, and expect to read the updated state value all within the same callback scope.

*However*, the following appears to work in "breaking up" the batching mechanism if you are wanting/needing to react to the intermediate "cleared state".

```js
<button
  onClick={async () => {
    await clearArr();
    addToArr();
  }}
>
  Clear Then Add
</button>
```

The above is certainly odd and historically wouldn't have worked, but the way state updates are processed have always been an internal implementation detail and subject to change.

If the above code makes you shiver inside like it does me, then the following is a slightly more conventional way to break up the enqueued updates. It uses a `setTimeout` call to place the second state update at the end of the Javascript event queue.

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    clearArr();
    setTimeout(addToArr, 0);
  }}
>
  Clear Then Add
</button>
```

### Demo

Demo using both implementations to break up the batched processing of the enqueued state updates.

[image: Edit how-to-respond-to-rapid-sequential-state-updates-with-usestate]

> ```
> []            // initial
> (1) [1]       // add
> (2) [1, 2]    // add
> (3) [1, 2, 3] // add
> []            // clear then add -> clean
> (1) [1]       // clear then add -> add
> ```

Comment: This is good stuff, thank you! Interesting and well written. The first example works in the Plunker (React 16.13) but not in my actual build (18.2). The `setTimeout` one works in both so I'm going with that for now. They all feel a little hacky but at this point I just want to get the thing working